# .Net Откуда берутся настройки прокси (кроме свойств браузера)?

Tags: .net, proxy

Случилась следующая ситуация:

На сервере запущена windows-служба, написанная на .Net. Служба периодически делает web-запросы. Настройки прокси в свойствах браузера пустые (нет ни одной галочки). В конфиге службы <имя службы>.config по поводу прокси ни единого слова (defaultProxy также отсутствует). Но с какого-то момента времени (кто что менял - выяснить не удалось) все веб-запросы стал резать наш прокси-сервер. По всем запросам служба получала 403ю ошибку от нашего прокси, который не так давно мы использовали все поголовно, но теперь в нем нет необходимости.

После длительных мучений выход был следующий:

```
request.Proxy = null;
```

Прям захардкожено. Ошибки ушли, запросы стали выполняться нормально.

Вопрос: откуда могут подтягиваться настройки прокси?

Я реально так и не понял почему вдруг WebRequest решил использовать прокси и откуда он взял его настройки.

И еще один симптом:

была написана консолька, которая вызывала один метод из библы той службы. Метод этот тупо делал get-запрос на проблемный url. Консолька удачно получала ответ, то есть не использовала прокси. А тот же код в службе откуда-то подтягивал настройки прокси... Откуда?!?))

---

Пример кода, в котором возникает проблема:

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.Proxy = null;

using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return Out;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы пользуетесь.

Comment: @VladD, да там все стандартнее некуда: var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
                req.Proxy = null;
                using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
                using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return Out;
                }

Answer (score 1):

Настройки браузера не являются общесистемными, они свои для каждого пользователя. Поэтому системные службы обычно используют настройки по умолчанию - а по умолчанию там стоит автоматическое определение настроек прокси через [WPAD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol)

Поищите упоминания прокси сервера в настройках вашего DHCP сервера, а также поищите домен wpad в вашей зоне DNS если она у вас есть.

Или же можете попробовать поискать файлы wpad.dat или proxy.pac на своем веб-сервере если копание в настройках DHCP и DNS вызывает затруднения.

Если ваш компьютер в домене, а вы - не админ домена, то в качестве быстрой проверки попробуйте открыть файл `http://wpad.{domain}/wpad.dat`. Тем самым вы проверите вариант "WPAD через DNS".

Также можно попробовать включить автоматическое определение в настройках браузера, после чего выполнить `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy("http://...")` чтобы понять какой именно прокси-сервер вы пытаетесь использовать.

Или можно добавить в вашу службу вывод результата этого вызова в лог.

PS если найдете настроенный WPAD - ни в коем случае не отключайте его, это сделает вашу локалку уязвимой. Лучше переписать содержимое wpad.dat/proxy.pac чтобы он говорил всем об отсутствии прокси-сервера.

Comment: Служба запускается от имени того же пользователя, под которым я ломился на сервер и под которым смотрел настройки браузера. С настройками DHCP покопаться не получится, буду админов пытать)

Comment: Если компьютер в АД, тоже можно еще в оснастке mmc "результирующая политика" поискать. или  gpresult еще можно попробовать посмотреть обмен в сети с помощью Microsoft Network Monitor

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, компьютер в домене, да, но по адресу http://wpad.{наш домен}/wpad.dat ничего нет

Comment: @jonsmith, ничего там не нашел(

Comment: В MSDN говорится другое.

Comment: @Qwertiy, эммм, можно помногословнее?) Вы про что?)

Comment: @СергейПолушин, я ж в своём ответе написал.

Comment: @Qwertiy что "другое" там говорится? Не вижу противоречий.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну я ж процитировал в своём ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy все еще не вижу противоречий

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [netsh winhttp](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx) Для Виндовс 7 и старше работает. В ХР был proxycfg

Comment: netsh winhttp show proxy даёт "Текущие параметры WinHTTP прокси. Прямой доступ (без прокси-сервера)"

Comment: Может у вас используется прозрачный прокси?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю что это такое( *ушел гуглить*

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то при прозрачном прокси "req.Proxy = null;" не решало бы эту проблему... ?) А она решается)

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpWebRequest.Proxy` на MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czdt10d3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The local computer or application config file may specify that a default proxy be used. If the Proxy property is specified, then the proxy settings from the Proxy property override the local computer or application config file and the HttpWebRequest instance will use the proxy settings specified. If no proxy is specified in a config file and the Proxy property is unspecified, the HttpWebRequest class uses the proxy settings inherited from Internet Explorer on the local computer. If there are no proxy settings in Internet Explorer, the request is sent directly to the server.

Дефаултный прокси может быть задан:

- Конфигурационный файл компьютера или приложения (приоритетно)
- Настройки Internet Explorer

Comment: "Конфигурационный файл компьютера" это machine.config имеется ввиду?

Comment: @СергейПолушин, подагаю, да. Но не проверял. И учти, что `machine.config` есть 2 штуки - один для x32 и один для x64.

Comment: Неа, ничего там не нашел. Касательно проксей там только <section name="defaultProxy" type="System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />. Да и консольное приложение тогда тоже подхватывало бы, если бы было что

Comment: @СергейПолушин, в реестре прокси проверь. У консольного приложения и у службы разные пользователи, под которыми они запущены.